# Fetch as Google Webmaster tools

Tags: angularjs, seo, google-search-console

I have an AngularJS SPA site which I wanted to test using google's "Fetch as Google" feature in webmaster tools. I am a little confused about the results. The screenshot from Googlebot looks correct however the response doesn't include any of the contents inside the "ui-view" (ui-router)... can someone explain what is happening here? Is google indexing the site properly since the screenshot is correct? Or is google not able to execute the JS properly for indexing?

Comment: This question should have a thousand upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mixed bag.  From some tests I've seen the GoogleBot is able to index some of the AJAX fetched content in some cases.  A safe bet though to make all the search engines happy is to use [prerender.io](http://prerender.io) or download their open source stuff (uses PhantomJS) to have your site be easily indexable.  Basically what this does is saves the version of your site after async operations have completed for a given URL and then you setup a redirect on your server that points any of the potential bots for search engines over to the preprocessed page.  It sounds pretty complicated but following the instructions on the site it's not too hard to setup, and if you don't want to pay for prerender.io to serve cached copies of your pages to search engines you can run the server component yourself too.

Comment: Helpful advice!  (But doesn't really answer the question.)

Comment: @SenseiJames if I had to guess I'd say the google bot does execute JS on the page but depending on resolves or redirects or whatever ui-router might be configured to do for a given site might not be as easy for the bot to 'know' how long to wait for operations to complete before scanning/indexing the page.  Using the prerender service or running your own version as mentioned in the answer allows you to more tightly control when the snapshot is captured (can set a variable on the window object to flag it to wait until you let it know the data/page is loaded)